# Where does Beast bring 5 original X-Men from past to present?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine-and-the-x-men

In a "Previously" blurb of "Wolverine and the X-Men #24", they say:

"Beast, ... made a desperate play of bringing the original five X-Men from the past to the present".

But I read every single "Wolverine and the X-Men" issue prior to 24 (including 23) and can't find a single mention of this event.

**Was this specific story covered in some other comics? If so, which?**

[image]

Comment: Didn't downvote, having never read them, but that blurb sounds more like the set up for a series, rather than a recap...

Comment: @Izkata - that's not how the usual "Previously" blurbs seemed to have worked. Regardless, that doesn't affect my main question (which comics was this covered in - wasn't W&XM)

Comment: @Izkata - the answer's date was released November 14, 2012. W&X-M #24 was released January 23, 2013. It WAS a recap, not future series, sorry.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xmen+comic+where+past+xmen+brought+to+present seems pretty obvious and trivial. First result being the Wikipedia page for *All-New X-Men*.

Comment: @Keen - that one now seems obvious in retrospect :( Thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those events occurred in [All New X-Men #1](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/43462/all-new_x-men_2012_1), and are the central premise of that comic series.